# Slider Function in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript

Hey I am working on a slider function for my app on Nativescript. Essentially I have to have a series of pictures that go on this slider. So for example the picture will go to the right if the slider is pulled to the right, and will go to the left if pulled to the left. I cannot figure out how to essentially anchor these pictures to the slider. Any help will be appreciated.

This is what I have in the Javascript file:

```
var observable = require("data/observable");

function pageLoaded(args) 
{
    var page = args.object;
    var viewModel = new observable.Observable();
    viewModel.set('sliderValue', 42);
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;

    viewModel.on(observable.Observable.propertyChangeEvent, function(propertyChangeData)
    {
        console.log('hi');
    });

}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

This is what I have in the XML file:

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded">
 <TabView>
   <TabView.items>

<TabViewItem title="Tab 1">
    <TabViewItem.view>


    <Slider value="10" />


    </TabViewItem.view>
</TabViewItem>

<TabViewItem title="Tab 2">
    <TabViewItem.view>
        <Image src="https://www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png" />
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>

<TabViewItem title="Tab 3">
    <TabViewItem.view>
        <Label text="Label in Tab3" />
    </TabViewItem.view>
</TabViewItem>


   </TabView.items>
 </TabView>
</Page>
```

Comment: Please include what you have done so far to try to solve this.

Comment: hi there. please give us some code so we can try it out.

Comment: I added some of the code I have. Hope this helps!

Comment: In this problem would I need to bind some sort of data together to the slider, I dont understand how I would give a picture a value. Any advise. Thanks!

Comment: @vampyfreak I don't see a Slider, do you mean the TabView?

Comment: @BradMartin I fixed it now I believe, sometimes the use of label text seems to break the slider in the tabbed views. I basically dont understand how one could assign a arbitrary values to pictures and use that to "slide" from one to the other. I am trying to create a time sensitive slideshow only using the slider as I think it could enrich the user UI experience. Thank you so much for helping me out!